# How to toggle a class on components added dynamically via computed in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Say you have a template:

```
<div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
  <p @click="toggle(item, $event)"> {{ item.name }} </p>
</div>
```

The items in this template come from a *computed property*:

`computed: { ...mapGetters(['items']) }`

I want to toggle a class when clicking on the `<p>` item (and not on it's siblings of course). Is there a simple way to go about doing this?

Is there a simple way to add a property to that individual `item` in the computed property and then do `:class="item.prop ? 'myclass' : ''"`? Preferably without having to do a dispatch just for this...

Would you instead tap on the element using `$event.target`, and if so, how would you toggle the class?

Answer (score 2):

[Something like this, perhaps?](https://jsfiddle.net/t716o85k/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
    <p @click="toggle($event)"> {{ item.name }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.my-class {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

**JS:**

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: [{ name: "Item1", id: "1" }, { name: "Item2", id: "2" }, { name: "Item3", id: "3" }]
  },
    methods: {
    toggle($event){
        let s = $event.target.classList;
      s.contains("my-class") ? s.remove("my-class") : s.add("my-class");
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: @CesarMartinezDominguez - if this answer helped resolve your issue, would you mind marking it as the accepted answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Best I figured out so far was:

```
data() {
  myClasses: {}
},
methods: {
  toggle(item) {
    if (this.myClasses[item.id]) {
      this.$set(this.myClasses, item.id, false)
    } else {
      this.$set(this.myClasses, item.id, true)
    }
  }
}
```

And use it like this in the component:

`<p @click="toggle(item)" :class="myClasses[item.id] ? 'myclass' : ''">`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
  <p @click="item.clicked=!item.clicked" 
     :class="{'class1':item.clicked, 'class2':!item.clicked}"> 
     {{ item.name }} 
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: That's not reactive in computed properties  :/  
That's why I had to use `$set` in my solution